# Aggregating features on time from individual samples

Tags: regression, feature-engineering

I am trying to solve a problem in which I need to figure out what is driving the daily/monthly total expenditure up over time. The data I have is something like this,

```
Item   Location Date  Type ...Expenditure
Item1   NY      Jan 1  A        100
Item2   NJ      Jan 5  B        200
...
```

It is a big table with many features on a per item basis. To be able to say what features are important in driving expenditure up over time, I was trying to roll up the data such that instead of a data point being a single item, a data point represents a time scale (a day/a month etc.) But if I do this, I need features to also represent the day or month rather than an item.

One way to do this would be to make separate features for every category of a categorical variable like Location and count how many times the categories occured during that day/month. But that gives me huge number of features.

I was wondering what if any specific methods I can look at to model such problems. Thanks.